# Consumir Api de terceros en laravel

Tags: laravel

Disculpen mi ignorancia pero estoy aprendiendo laravel y tengo que hacer un acceso con login pero la autenticación es por medio de API de un tercero mi pregunta es ¿Dónde va la URL de la api?, He visto varios tutoriales pero todos son api locales y en el .env están los datos de la BD pero en mi caso solo tengo el http de la api y nada más, no se si va en el controlador o en el formulario, se agradece vuestras respuestas.

```
<form class="register-user-form" method="POST" action="**direccion de la API/LOGIN**">
        @csrf
        
        <label>
            <input name="username" type="name" placeholder="Nombre...">
        </label><br>
        <label>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña...">
        </label><br>
        
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

En action he puesto el link pero me manda este resultado en la dirección de la API
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ORM.png

esta es la función en el controlador

```
 public function iniciarSesion(Request $request)
    {
        $credenciales = array(
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($credenciales)) {
            // Authentication passed...;
            return "SI";
            return redirect()->route('core.get.dashboard');
            
        }
        //La autenticación no ha funcionado
        return "NO";
    }
```

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Pero si la api es de un tercero lo mas conveniente es consultar el endpoint atraves de javascript, con fetch, axios o ajax... etc